# Counting nickels, dimes and quarters, order matters.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> A parking meter costs 5 cents per minute and only accepts the nickels, dimes or quarters.  How many different ways can $n$ minutes be purchased by inserting coins into the parking meter where the order in which the coins are inserted matters?  Let $A_n$ be the number of ways $n$ minutes can be purchased and assume that the correct initial values have been defined for $A_0, A_1, A_2$, etc. have been defined as needed.  Recall that 1 quarter = 25 cents, 1 dime =10 cents, and 1 nickel = 5 cents.

> Answer choices
>
> 1. $A_n = A_{n-5} + A_{n-2} + A_{n-1}$
> 2. $A_n = A_{n-25} + A_{n-10} + A_{n-5}$
> 3. $A_n = A_{n-5} \cdot  A_{n-2} \cdot  A_{n-1}$
> 4. $A_n = 5\cdot A_{n-5} +2\cdot A_{n-2} + A_{n-1}$

**Part of my work or
Explanation and Justification:** 
The simpler rows are justified by writing out the sequences.
I explain more complex rows with the following formula.
w-xNyDzQ
xN represents number of Nickels
yD represents number of Dimes
zQ represents number of Quarters
w is the number of permutations of that set of nickels, dimes and quarters.
Note: "order matters" so 15 cents from ND is different from DN

Ex. From row $A_4$, 3-2N1D represents two nickels and one dime.  NND, NDN, DNN is 3 permutations.

| $A_n$ | Value | Count | Justification |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $A_0$ | 0 | 0 | {null set is empty**} |
| $A_1$ | 5 | 1 | {N} |
| $A_2$ | 10 | 2 | {NN}, {D} |
| $A_3$ | 15 | 3 | {N}, {ND, DN} |
| $A_4$ | 20 | 5 | NNNN, 3-2N1D, DD |
| $A_5$ | 25 | 9 | 1-5N, 4-3ND, 3-1N2D, 1Q |
| $A_6$ | 30 | 14 | 1-6N, 5-4N,1D, 6-2N2D, 2-QN |

** In my humble opinion, I.M.H.O., $A_0$ should be excluded from the question to make the recursive rule work.

However, my $A_4$, $A_5$, $A_6$ don't fit any of the options given for recursive formulas.
$A_{n-25}$ would be related 125 cents prior, not 25 cents prior, so option 2 is pretty clearly incorrect.  Option  3 and option 4 seem to be growing far quicker than my table.
Option 1 is the closest fit, but breaks down on $A_6$.

Comment: I will elaborate more on my justification for counts later.

Comment: $A_n$ is the number of ways to purchase $n$ minutes, but your table makes out it's the number of ways to purchase $5n$ minutes. Maybe the heading for the 2nd column should be "value".

Comment: Also, $A_0$ should be one, not zero – there is one way to purchase zero minutes, and that one way is to insert no coins at all.

Comment: And I get $A_6=15$.

Comment: Ahhhhh, I'm missing the three dimes option on $A_6$.  Yeah, that should fix it.

Comment: @hardmath  I don't know the source.  A student shared this question with me.

Comment: Conceptually, the number of ways to pay the meter is the number of ways where the last coin buys $5$ minutes, plus the number of ways where the last coin buys $2$ minutes, plus the number of ways where the last coin buys $1$ minute. Which is exactly what answer choice 1 says.

Comment: The recursive rule works, if you realize that $A_0=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @GerryMyerson I figured it out.  I was missing the 3 dimes permutation in the $A_6$ row.  That row should list a count of 15 which is consistent with the recursive formula for multiple choice 1.

Comment: I'm intentionally leaving my original answer in the table.  I think high school and college students might benefit from seeing that mistakes are normal.